# Modifying BubbleSort Code

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I am trying to study for a test and one of the study questions I can't get deals with BubbleSort. The question is:

Modify the BubbleSort code below to short circuit its execution. By that I mean, modify it so that if a pass is completed without making any swaps, execution will stop.

```
public static<T extends Comparable<T>> void bubbleSort(T[] data)
{
  int position, scan;
  T temp;

  for (position = data.length - 1; position >= 0; position--)
  {
    for (scan = 0; scan <= position - 1; scan++)
    {
      if (data[scan].compareTo(data[scan+1]) > 0)
      {
        /**Swap the values*/
        temp = data[scan];
        data[scan] = data[scan+1];
        data[scan + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need a boolean flag or a state.

A quick google search would have saved you the trouble: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort

```
repeat
    hasChanged := false
    decrement itemCount
    repeat with index from 1 to itemCount
        if (item at index) > (item at (index + 1))
            swap (item at index) with (item at (index + 1))
            hasChanged := true
until hasChanged = false
```

Comment: I guess I missed that link but thank you! I really appreciate it